# Image loading with Glide in GridView is too slow

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am showing about 50+ images with url from server in GridView which has image(120*120)
when loading images taking too much time. Average original images size is around 50-200 KB

Glide Code:

In GridViewAdapter

```
RequestOptions reqOpt = RequestOptions.fitCenterTransform().transform(new RoundedCorners(5));
    ...
GlideApp
      .with(context)
      .load(item.getUrl())
      .apply(reqOpt)
      .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
      .into(holder.ivThumb);
```

In Gradle

```
...
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
...
```

Comment: Did you check your internet connection? Might be slow internet connection cause an issue.

Answer (score 6):

**Try this**,

It'll optimize your memory for loading images.

```
RequestOptions reqOpt = RequestOptions
                            .fitCenterTransform()
                            .transform(new RoundedCorners(5))
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) // It will cache your image after loaded for first time
                            .override(holder.ivThumb.getWidth(),holder.ivThumb.getHeight()) // Overrides size of downloaded image and converts it's bitmaps to your desired image size;
```

Checkout more from here : [Glide reference](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html#requestoptions)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let me know if this is the workaround for you! @P. Bruegel

Answer (score 4):

You can use in Thumbnail -

```
GlideApp.with(context)
 .load(item.getUrl())
 .thumbnail(/*sizeMultiplier=*/ 0.25f)
 .apply(reqOpt)
 .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
 .into(holder.ivThumb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this when you get image from URL, this code reduces the size of that image

you can also do this,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

//save scaled down image to cache dir
newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

File imageFile = new File(filePath);

// write the bytes in file
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Please try this. This could help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use picaso ,,it will be load faster than glide

```
Picasso.get()
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
.into(imageView);

 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```